# python or vs explicit if for value assignment

Tags: python

When going through some codebases in python I saw some expressions which roughly translates to the code below:

```
def foo(a=None):
    b = a or {'key1': 'val1', 
           'key2': 'val2',
           'key3': 'val3'
         }
```

The above can also be written as:

```
def foo(a=None):
    if a is None :
    b = {
          'key1': 'val1', 
          'key2': 'val2',
          'key3': 'val3'
         }

    # now  we can use b here
```

is it just about the coding style or any other benefit that we might have in python considering `or` vs `if` evaluation ?

Comment: The two snippets are not equivalent: if `a` is False (and `not None`), it may give you a different result.

Comment: the first code will return the value of b as dictionary if a is none or if a have any value it will return a value

Comment: second one will not have a case when none nothing will be displayed

Comment: @MidhunMohan i understand what the first code does.

Comment: @anekix the second one will work only if the value of a is none what about if a is not none

Comment: @MidhunMohan let me edit the question . i just hardcoded the value making `a = None` .

Comment: okay get the question clear so that we could help you better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences between the two.

The `b = a or {}` syntax will assign `{}` to `b` if `a` is any 'falsey' value (i.e. `0`, `''`, `False`, ...).

Performing an explicit check with:

```
if a is None:
    b = {}
else:
    b = a
```

will assign `{}` to `b` only if `a` is `None`. Any other 'falsey' values for `a` will ensure the `else` branch is used.

**Edit:**

Having seen your updated question, it seems that the `a=None` is being assigned in the function def. This is a very common practice to avoid having mutable default values for function arguments. See [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html) for a quick rundown on why this is done.

The standard approach for assigning default parameters in this setting is:

```
def my_func(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = [1,2,3,4] #The default, mutable structure that you want to assign to x.
```

I would avoid taking shortcuts with `x = x or [...]`, unless you're absolutely sure that the user shouldn't pass in a value that will evaluate as false. Even then, better to be explicit.

Comment: thanks . i have slightly modified my question , your answer still answers my question. all i want to know in the function is .if some value for a has been supplied use that value or else if its not supplied use the default value that i have( the dictionary here in this case).

Comment: `better to be explicit` this is what i had in mind when i asked this question :)

Comment: Another link that also covers a few other 'gotchas' - http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/